# How to prevent array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program to maximize the profit made in buying and selling shares. I am trying to check if the value in the next index is greater than the value in the current index position however my loops results in array out of bounds. Its occurs at this line  **if((shares[i]) < (shares[i+1]).)** What is the best approach to prevent this.

Edit: I have been given a list of share prices. Each day I can either buy or sell buy or sell. My approach is to find the average of the share prices. If the price is below the average then "buy" if the next days price lower still then hold "buy". And vice versa. if number is greater than the average then sell, if the day afterwards is greater still then hold sale. Ideally at shares[9] I will buy at €4 and at at shares[11] I will sell at €19. However when it comes to check whether to sell or not to ends up array out of bounds as it try to check the next index after shares[11].

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] shares ={3,7,4,2,10,11,8,5,4,8,19};
    int average= 0;
    int  buyOrSell = 0;
    int profit = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< shares.length; i++)
    {
        average += shares[i];
    }

    average  /= shares.length;
    System.out.println(average);

    for(int i = 0; i < shares.length; i++)
    {
            if((shares[i] <= average) && (buyOrSell == 0))
            {
                if((shares[i]) < (shares[i+1]))
                {
                System.out.println("Buy" + shares[i]);
                buyOrSell++;
                System.out.println("Profit: " + (profit -= shares[i]));
                }
                else System.out.println("Hold Buy" + shares[i]);

            }

            if(shares[i] >= average && buyOrSell == 1)
            {
                if((shares[i]) > (shares[i+1]))
                {
                System.out.println("Sell" + shares[i]);
                buyOrSell--;
                System.out.println("Profit: " + (profit += shares[i]));
                }

                else System.out.println("Hold Sell" + shares[i]);
            }


    }

    System.out.println("Profit: "+ profit);

}
```

Thanks to Gambs solution I added this if statement to solve my problem.

```
if((i == shares.length -1)  && buyOrSell == 1 && (shares[i] >= average)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sell" + shares[i]);
            buyOrSell--;
            System.out.println("Profit: " + (profit += shares[i]));
            break;

        }
```

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger to observe the line that is failing?  Or even read your exception to determine the line that is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from implementing a range restriction like everyone correctly suggested, you have to contemplate the *border case* for the last item of the array. If you iterate until `length - 2`, what happens with with the element in the position `length - 1`?

There are two approaches you can take. One is to iterate until `length - 2` and then handling the last element outside the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < shares.length - 1; i++)
//Your code
int finalShare = shares[length - 1];
//Manage the final item here
```

The other one consists in keeping the iteration as it is, while adding a particular check that determines if the end of the iteration has been reached, handles the final element and then breaks the iteration.

```
for(int i = 0; i < shares.length; i++) {
    if(i == length - 1) {
        //handle final element here...
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you reach the end of the array, the `shares[i+1]` will throw an exception. You should decrease the limit in the loop by one: `for(int i = 0; i < shares.length - 1; i++)`

Comment: However this does not allow to check whether or not if I should sell in the last index?

Comment: Could you please re-write your comment.. It's hard to understand it.

Comment: Apologies I will try to clarify in the main post.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays start at 0, so `shares[i+1]` is out of bounds when `i == shares.length`

Depending on your logic, there are a lot of things you can do, such as

change

```
if((shares[i]) < (shares[i+1]))
```

to

```
if((i+1 < shares.length) && (shares[i]) < (shares[i+1]))
```

or to

```
if((shares[i-1]) < (shares[i]))
```

or you can change the condition in your loop to

```
for(int i = 0; i < shares.length - 1; i++)
```

it all depends on how your logic works

Comment: I was exactly going to address the way you did... nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `for` loop looks at the index `[i+1]`, which is out of bounds for the last iteration of the loop, when `i == length - 1`. To fix this, your loop should iterate to `length - 1` as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < shares.length - 1; i++) 
{...}
```

This way, you can always access `[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop runs from `i=0` to `i=shares.length-1`. This means that the maximum value taken by `i` is `shares.length-1`. Therefore, doing `shares[i+1]` is equivalent to doing `shares[shares.length]`. That is why you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because array indexes start from `0` not `1`. You can avoid it by changing the loop condition to `i < shares.length-1`.